# Can't get firebase user info from provider

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm facing problem when I try to fetch data with the help of a provider. Everything looks okay but still i can't make it.

```
//Provider
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Injectable()
export class SomeProvider {
user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
  }

this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {console.log(user.uid)}); // i can get UID with this
........
```

But when I call it here it returns undefined:

```
//menu.ts
import { SomeProvider } from '../../providers/some/some';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-menu',
  templateUrl: 'menu.html',
})
export class MenuPage {

constructor(private cfg: SomeProvider, private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth){}
ionViewDidLoad(){ 
console.log(this.cfg.user.uid);  //returns undefined
.....
```

I have tried firebase SDK but getting same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `firebase` import needed for `user: Observable<firebase.User>;`, if you haven't already, you should be importing it in `SomeProvider`:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

Also, as per your code, `user` is an Observable, therefore you need to subscribe to it:

```
export class MenuPage {

  constructor(private cfg: SomeProvider, private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth){}
  ionViewDidLoad(){ 
    this.cfg.user.subscribe(user => console.log(user.uid));
```

---

Alternatively:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeProvider {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  userId: string; // initialize

  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
    this.user.subscribe(user => this.userId = user.uid); // assign userId here
  }

  get getUserId(): string {
    return this.userId;
  }
```

Then in the component:

```
export class MenuPage {

  constructor(private cfg: SomeProvider, private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth){}
  ionViewDidLoad(){ 
    console.log(this.cfg.getUserId); // user id should be logged here
```

Comment: How to return data like this `profile(req){this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {return user.req})};` currentUser seems not working as expected.

Comment: That will return you an actual `subscription` object, which is why it won't work. If you want just return static values from your service I would suggest subscribing to `authState` in your service `constructor` and assigning the value you want to a class property. Will update with an example

Comment: I understood. But it's static value that will add more codes in script which can be done in menu by 1 line code. Thanks for your quick response